# How to clear the cache for diferred object for below example

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint, jquery-deferred

I am using following code to retrieve the data from the sharepoint.

```
RESTQueries.getItemsFromList = function(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var execute = function(listName,itemId){
        if(typeof(listName)=='undefined' || listName.length==0  ){
            deferred.reject('getItemsFromList - no proper list name');
            return deferred;
        }
        var formatUrl = currentSiteUrl;
        formatUrl = (formatUrl.lastIndexOf('/')==(formatUrl.length-1))?formatUrl:(formatUrl+'/');
        var _url = (typeof(itemId)=='undefined' || itemId=='0')? (formatUrl+"_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items") :  (formatUrl+"_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items("+itemId+")");
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            method:'GET',
            headers:{Accept:'application/json; odata=verbose'},
            success:function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            error:function(err){
                deferred.reject(err.responseJSON.error.message.value);
            }
        });
        return deferred;
    };
    return {
        execute:execute 
    }
}();
```

To execute this function I am calling this like

```
RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute('Pages').done(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

This is giving the result without any issues. 
But the problem is, if I call it for second time for different library like,

```
RESTQueries.getItemsFromList.execute('Students').done(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

In this case also result is same as first request.
I think some where it is caching the response. How to clear the response for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs since the instance

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
```

is created *outside* of `execute` function scope. When `execute` function is called for the second time the `done` method is getting called for the resolved Deferred object from the previous call.

**Solution**

Move the declaration of `deferred` object into the scope of `execute` function:

```
var execute = function(listName,itemId){
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including this in your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax ({
    ...
    cache: false,
    ...
});
```